# How to combine both c type and python type into a struct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

The old code uses two global variables as follows:

```
# global variables
cdef uint64_t g_num = 0
car_type = None
```

How can I design a struct that can be used to contain both g_num and car_type?
Here is the psudo-code:

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__(self):
        car_type = None
        g_num ??? how to define it as an uint64_t?

cdef class Car:
    uint64_t g_num
    car_type  ?? what is the type here?
```

Basically, I need to put the combined type into a dict so that I can use the following code:

```
d = {}
d['aaa'] = Car()
d['aaa'].g_num = 1
d['aaa'].car_type = 'Compact'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to define your Cython-class as:

```
%%cython
cdef class Car:
    cdef public unsigned long long int g_num
    cdef public object car_type
```

Behind the scenes Cython creates properties (thus `public` is needed) `g_num` and `car_type`. It takes care of initializing `g_num` to `0`and `car_type` to `None`. Cython also takes care of decreasing the reference count of the object bound to `car_type` when `__del__` is called.

Now we it works as wished:

```
>>> car=Car()
>>> car.g_num
0L
>>> car.car_type is None
True
>>> car.car_type="Compact"
>>> car.car_type
'Compact'
```

---

There is a subtly difference between properties of python-objects (`object`) and c-members (for example `int`, `long long int` and so on):

In the first case we get the reference to the python-object and could change it. For example:

```
>>> car=Car()
>>> car.car_type=[1,2]
>>> lst=car.car_type
>>> lst.append(6) #changes also car.car_type!
>>> car.car_type
[1,2,6]
```

In the second case a new python-object will be created by cython and changing it will not change the original member of the object for which the property was called.

It is not that unexpected in this simple example, because `long long int' will be returned as an immutable python-integer, but we could use a struct to illustrate the point:

```
%%cython
cdef struct S:
    int a
    int b
cdef class A:
    cdef public S s

>>> a=A()
>>> s=a.s
>>> type(s) #it is a python-dictionary:
dict
>>> s.keys() #member names are the keys:
['a', 'b']
>>> s['a'] #initialized to 0
0
>>> s['a']=100
>>> a.s # the last change didn't propagate back to the object a!
{'a': 0, 'b': 0}
```

---

To backup my claim, that `g_num` and `car_type` are initialized (which is not obvious). Important things happen here:

```
static PyObject *__pyx_tp_new_4test_Car(PyTypeObject *t, CYTHON_UNUSED PyObject *a, CYTHON_UNUSED PyObject *k) {
  struct __pyx_obj_4test_Car *p;
  PyObject *o;
  if (likely((t->tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_IS_ABSTRACT) == 0)) {
    o = (*t->tp_alloc)(t, 0);
  } else {
    o = (PyObject *) PyBaseObject_Type.tp_new(t, __pyx_empty_tuple, 0);
  }
  if (unlikely(!o)) return 0;
  p = ((struct __pyx_obj_4test_Car *)o);
  p->car_type = Py_None; Py_INCREF(Py_None);
  return o;
}
```

One can see directly, that `car_type` is set to `None` in the line

```
p->car_type = Py_None; Py_INCREF(Py_None);
```

Less obvious is how `g_num` is set to `0`. It happens when [`tp_alloc`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_alloc) of the `PyTypeObject` is called, because in its course the memory (and also `g_num`) is initialized with `0`.

The reference of `car_type` is decreased in `__pyx_tp_dealloc_4test_Car` via `Py_CLEAR(p->car_type)`:

```
static void __pyx_tp_dealloc_4test_Car(PyObject *o) {
  struct __pyx_obj_4test_Car *p = (struct __pyx_obj_4test_Car *)o;
  #if CYTHON_USE_TP_FINALIZE
  if (unlikely(PyType_HasFeature(Py_TYPE(o), Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_FINALIZE) && Py_TYPE(o)->tp_finalize) && !_PyGC_FINALIZED(o)) {
    if (PyObject_CallFinalizerFromDealloc(o)) return;
  }
  #endif
  PyObject_GC_UnTrack(o);
  Py_CLEAR(p->car_type);  
  (*Py_TYPE(o)->tp_free)(o);
}
```